# RegEx Split method in C# is returning an empty string because of the specified pattern at EOF. How can I avoid this behaviour?

Tags: c#, regex

I've built this method which accepts a stream of text with \n characters and discriminates each line in a string array:

```
private static string[] SerialToLines(string serializedText)
    {
        string newLinePattern = "\r\n|\r|\n";
        string[] linesData = Regex.Split(serializedText, newLinePattern);

        return linesData;
    }
```

The issue is that the input files MAY (I just can't be certain) present \r\n right in the end of `serializedText`, which generates an additional empty item in the output string array and leads to errors down the line in my program. Is there a way to use RegEx explicitly (or RegEx methods) to avoid this sort of behaviour? For now, I'm going to check manually for an additional empty string, but I'd love to see a RegEx-based workaround for this.

As an appendix, I'll leave an excerpt of the type of text which is usually handed as `serializedText` :

> 0.333333333333241 0.3333333333339809 0.6666666666657874\r\n
> 0.333333333333241 0.3333333333339809 0.333333333332501\r\n
> 0.3333333333339809 0.6666666666669905 0.6666666666657874\r\n
> 0.3333333333339809 0.6666666666669905 0.333333333332501\r\n
> 0.6666666666663889 0.3333333333332409 0.6666666666657873\r\n
> 0.6666666666663887 0.3333333333332411 0.333333333332501\r\n
> 0.6666666666669904 0.6666666666663887 0.6666666666657874\r\n
> 0.6666666666669905 0.6666666666663887 0.333333333332501\r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this what you are looking for

```
string newLinePattern = @"\\r\\n|\\r|\\n| ";
string[] linesData = Regex.Split(serializedText, newLinePattern);

return linesData.Where(d =>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'd just add the need of adding (using System.Linq;) but that's all

Answer (score 0):

Use `serializedText.TrimEnd('\n').TrimEnd('\r')` inside the `Regex.Split(...)` call instead of `serializedText`.